# The text in UIStatusBar does not change to white when navigation bar style was UIBarStyleBlack

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uistatusbar

if the navigation bar style is UIBarStyleDefault, the status bar style will be UIStatusBarStyleDefault; if the navigation bar style is UIBarStyleBlack, the status bar style will be UIStatusBarStyleLightContent.
In my project,navigation bar style is **UIBarStyleBlack**,but text in UIStatusBar still **black**.why?

Answer (score 0):

i think you missed to add

```
View controller-based status bar appearance == no
```

in your plist so by default it is taking black appearance for you status bar. make sure when you are adding it in your plist type should be Boolean.

Answer (score 0):

in iOS 9 By default the status bar color is black color.So you need to do the below things.

If you use XIB,follow the below code

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   self.window setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
   [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
   [application setStatusBarHidden:NO];
   self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
   UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
   [self.window setRootViewController:navController];
   [navController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

   return YES;
}
```

If you use StoryBoard,apply the below code

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
  [application setStatusBarHidden:NO];
  return YES;
}
```

in your project-info.plist

```
View controller-based status bar appearance   Boolean   NO
Status bar is initially hidden                Boolean   NO
```